# Is it possible to pass an object of type class as an argument in another class so that I don't have to initialize again ? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, python-class

I use two classes `Foo` and `Bar` where the later inherits from the first.
It can take some time to run `Foo` and when I need to run `Bar` I don't want to run it again.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = "something"
        self.another_variable = 10
        # and many other variables

    def do_something(self):
        self.something = "something else"
        self.another_variable = 100
        # and more operations on the other variables

        print(f"This takes some time. We have {self.something!r} now.")

foo = Foo()
foo.do_something() # This takes some time. We have 'something else' now.


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, foo=None):
        if isinstance(foo, Foo):
            self.something = foo.something
            self.another_variable = foo.another_variable
            # ...
            # this is the part that I want to generalize
            # with something that would intuitively look like 'self = foo'
        else:
            Foo.__init__(self)
            self.do_something()

    def print_something(self):
        print(self.something)

bar = Bar(foo=foo)
bar.print_something() # AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'something'
```

I would like to do something like `self = foo` so that everything done with `foo` can be passed to `bar` without running the code again.

I know I can do `Bar().foo()` and then `Bar().bar()` and this is what I actually do now, but I would like to initialise `bar` only at a later stage.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Since Bar is a child class of Foo, Create an instance of Bar which initializes foo, if and only if the Bar instantiation doesn't include Foo.  Just because you define a class it isn't executed until it is instantiated, so Foo is only instantiated once.

Comment: If you only need `Foo`  once in your entire project, you might want to look into another design. Something like a Singleton of some sorts or add it as a static value.
So the question is, do you need Foo only once?

Comment: I would like to use `Foo` multiple times before using `Bar`. Then, when the parameters of `foo` are good enough, I would like to pass each of its elements and methods to `bar` without running it again (and without doing it manually).
What I do at the moment is initialize multiple times `Bar`, but only run the methods from `Foo`, until I have the correct parameters, and only then I use the rest of `Bar`. It works. But it's not so pretty.

Comment: It sounds to me like Foo has a method or set of methods that should be coded as a stand-alone function rather that part of Foo.  In this wat, the function(s) can be called when required, and only when needed.  The function can take as input Foo and Bar

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, you can do that with a flag (here named `self.processed`):

```
from time import sleep


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = "something"
        self.processed = False

    def do_something(self):
        self.something = "something else"
        sleep(1)
        self.processed = True
        print(f"This takes some time. We have {self.something!r} now.")


foo = Foo()
foo.do_something()  # This takes some time. We have 'something else' now.


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, foo=None):
        if isinstance(foo, Foo):
            super().__init__()

            if not foo.processed:
                self.do_something()

    def print_something(self):
        print(self.something)


bar = Bar(foo=foo)
bar.print_something()
```

output :

```
This takes some time. We have 'something else' now.
something else
```

So in `Bar`'s initialization, `do_something` method only gets called if we haven't called that before ( on `foo` )

Comment: Thank you @ SorousH for your answer, but this is not what I am looking for :
I am looking for a single (or so) line that would pass every variable and methods from one class (e.g. `Foo`) to another (e.g. `Bar`). I have not found a way yet

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a solution by looping over the attributes:

```
for attr in foo.__dict__.keys():
    exec(f"self.{attr} = foo.{attr}")
```

Here is the full working example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = "Something"
        self.another_variable = 10
        # and many other variables

    def run_foo(self):
        self.something = "Something else"
        self.another_variable = 100
        # and more operations on the other variables
        print(f"This takes some time. We have {self.something!r} now.")

foo = Foo()
foo.run_foo()               # This takes some time. We have 'something else' now.
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, foo=None):
        if isinstance(foo, Foo):
            for attr in foo.__dict__.keys():      # this is the solution
                exec(f"self.{attr} = foo.{attr}") #
            print("'run_foo' is not called, so there is no waste of time.")
        else:
            Foo.__init__(self)
            self.run_foo()

    def print_something(self):
        print(self.something)

bar = Bar()                 # This takes some time. We have 'something else' now.
bar.print_something()       # Something else

bar = Bar(foo=foo)          # 'run_foo' is not called, so there is no waste of time.
bar.print_something()       # Something else
```